# WPF - Can't move cursor to a TextBox on ViewModel property change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**Context**

A WPF application based on MVVM (no frameworks). The XAML appears below.

**Issue**
The ViewModel property EditingState gets changed through an ICommand whenever the searchRegistration TextBox loses focus. In this instance EditingState changes to "Search" which causes a number of triggers.  For the airframeBasicDetails grid, the grid should become enabled, have a blue background and have the edit cursor set into the typeName field. This works *except that the cursor is not set*.  Indeed it's not visible anywhere in the window. This establishes that the state change took place and the trigger fired but for some reason the cursor didn't move.

**Question**

How do I move the edit cursor to typeName when EditingState becomes "Search"?

**Note**

I built a simplified version of this app which works perfectly.  I've looked for differences between that version and the problem version but can't find anything hence I'm posting the whole failing script paired down as best I can.  I'm reluctant to remove too much lest the issue lie with something I've removed.

```
<Window x:Class="ADB_Desktop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ADB_Desktop"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=DotNetProjects.Input.Toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ADB Desktop"
        Width="1100"
        Height="800"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=searchRegistration}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Binding proxy-->
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel Name="mainDockPanel" LastChildFill="True">
        <Menu Name="mainMenu" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Menu.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ADBMenuStatusBarColour}"/>
            </Menu.Background>
            <MenuItem Header="_Maintenance"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Reports"/>
        </Menu>
        <StatusBar x:Name="statusBar" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="25">
            <StatusBar.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ADBMenuStatusBarColour}"/>
            </StatusBar.Background>
        </StatusBar>
        <TabControl x:Name="mainTabControl" Background="{DynamicResource ADBMainBackgroundColour}" SelectedIndex="1">
            <TabItem Header="Gallery"/>
            <TabItem Header="Airframes">
                <Grid x:Name="airframesGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="airframeAndImageRow" Height="380"/>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="identitiesRow"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="airframeCell" Width="400"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="pictureCell"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="searchRow" Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="detailsRow" Height="180"/>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="sightingsFlightRow" Height="120"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" Margin="2">
                                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="searchLabelCell" MaxWidth="100"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="searchCell" MinWidth="180"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="researchCell"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Registration:"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBox x:Name="searchRegistration" CharacterCasing="Upper" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Height="20" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                     Text="{Binding SearchRegistration, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchSaveCommand}"/>
                                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <TextBox.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EditingState}" Value="{x:Static local:EditingState.Initial}">
                                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EditingState}" Value="{x:Static local:EditingState.Search}">
                                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EditingState}" Value="{x:Static local:EditingState.New}">
                                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </TextBox.Style>
                                            </TextBox>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                      </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" Margin="2">
                                <Grid Name="airframeBasicDetails" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
                                    <Grid.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EditingState}" Value="{x:Static local:EditingState.Initial}">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EditingState}" Value="{x:Static local:EditingState.Search}">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=typeName}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EditingState}" Value="{x:Static local:EditingState.New}">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=typeName}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Grid.Style>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="airframeLabels" MaxWidth="100"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="airframeDetails"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition x:Name="typeRow"/>
                                        <RowDefinition x:Name="constructionNoRow"/>
                                        <RowDefinition x:Name="remarksRow"/>
                                        <RowDefinition x:Name="rolledOutDateRow"/>
                                        <RowDefinition x:Name="firstFlightDateRow"/>
                                        <RowDefinition x:Name="statusRow"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Type</Label>
                                    <controls:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Height="20" Width="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             Name="typeName"
                                             Text="{Binding Path=AirframeCollectionView/TypeName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TypeNames}"
                                                    IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                                    FilterMode="Contains" >
                                     </controls:AutoCompleteBox>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Construction no</Label>
                                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" x:Name="constructionNo" Height="20" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             Text="{Binding AirframeCollectionView/ConstructionNumber}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="airframePicture" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                   </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Revisiting my simplified example I note that I was using a button to trigger the change to EditingState.  When I changed the trigger to be tabbing out of a TextBox as per my problem code the issue arises.  I therefore think this has something to do with the effect of using the Tab key I.e. the Tab key has the effect of further changing focus after the trigger has completed its work.  The search continues...

Comment: I believe so as well -- trying to change the focus while the UI thread is already busy changing the focus and in the midst of processing focus-related events is probably asking for trouble. Why don't you try postponing your focus changing until the UI thread has been finished with all the focus-related processing? (For example, by adding the respective operation(s) to the dispatcher queue with the help of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`)

Comment: @elgonzo Good idea.  This will be my first foray into the wacky world of the Dispatcher so I may take a little time to put a solution together.  I'm thinking this will involve reducing the priority of the ICommand so that Tab processing can complete in the UI thread before the ICommand causes state change and the resultant data triggers.  I'll post something when I have it working and can then mark your observations as the answer.

Comment: @elgonzo Ok, many thanks, this is now fixed.  See the edit of my question  for details of the way I tackled it.  Happy to mark your contribution as the answer if you'd care to do the necessary.

Comment: It is possible for you to answer your own question. Actually, you more or less already did. Just copy pasta the solution you wrote in your question into an answer, and voila... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per elgonzo's advice this has been resolved by introducing a short delay in the execution of the ICommand actions.  This allows the UI focus updates caused by Tabbing out of a field to complete before changing EditingState and triggering further changes to focus.  To implement this the following has been included in the ICommand class:

```
    public delegate void ChangeEditingStateDelegate();

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // Actions defered through Dispatcher because:
        // - The actions invoke triggers which change focus
        // - User may Tab out of a field invoking this command.
        // - If so, the UI thread needs to finish default Tab focus updates before these further actions occur.
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ChangeEditingStateDelegate(this.ChangeEditingState));
    }

    private void ChangeEditingState()
    {
        // The current editing state determines what this command button should be doing
        switch (this.viewModel.EditingState)
        {
            case EditingState.Initial:
                // Search for airframes
                this.SearchForAirframes();
                break;
            case EditingState.Search:
                // Save edits
                this.SaveUpdates();
                break;
            case EditingState.New:
                // Save new airframe
                this.SaveUpdates();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown editing state");
        }
    }
```